# How pass a variable in stripe CLI post request

Tags: express, stripe-payments

I want to save a variable and be able to pass it further after the page has been reloaded. So i want to get the `req.session.variable` and be able to use it in `router.post('/webhook', ...)` which is controled by Stripe CLI. Inside of this post request the `req.session.variable` is unavailable because the site has redirected the user to another website which clears the `req.session` content, moreove the content of `req.body` inside the *post request* is by default in `req.rawBody` format. Is there a way i can pass this variable into the request and use it with ease?

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let postMong = require('./post')
require("dotenv").config()
router.use(express.json());
const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:4242';
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.PUBLIC_KEY);
const endpointSecret = 'whsec_1c7320d5c8878c54d6f99e0d5dcd441008c79b76ddb0a09727a4fd977d3ac1ed';
const fulfillOrder = (ses) => {
  console.log("Order Completed")
}


router.post('/checkout/create-order', async (req, res) => {
  const price = req.body.order.stripe_price || undefined,
        product = req.body.order.stripe_product || undefined
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    //shipping_address_collection: {
    //  allowed_countries: ['US', 'CA'],
    //},
    //shipping_options: [
    //  {
    //    shipping_rate_data: {
    //      type: 'fixed_amount',
    //      fixed_amount: {
    //        amount: 2499,
    //        currency: 'usd',
    //      },
    //      display_name: 'International Shipping',
    //      // Delivers between 5-7 business days
    //      delivery_estimate: {
    //        minimum: {
    //          unit: 'week',
    //          value: 2,
    //        },
    //      }
    //    }
    //  },
    //],
    line_items: [
      {
        price: price,
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    payment_method_types: ["card", 'us_bank_account'],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success.html`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/index.html`,
  });

  res.json({url: session.url})
});


router.post('/webhook', (request, response) => {
  const payload = request.body;
let username = request.session.username; // returns undefined because the session is empty after the redirect
  const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
  let event;
  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
    return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
    const session = event.data.object;
    fulfillOrder(session);
  }

  response.status(200);
});

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you need to store as information you have a couple of different options, but in all cases it’s best if you use the Checkout Session Object[0] to store what you need.
If you’re looking to pass a reference id (e.g. customer id or cart id from your app) you can use `client_reference_id`[1]. If you need to pass more info than you can rely to the `metadata`[2] hash where you can input as much information as you need.

Since you’ve already got a webhook endpoint configured, you will have access to both of these fields in your `session`  object after the session is complete.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-client_reference_id

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata

Comment: that looks exactly like what i need, but why when i pass some new arguments there, and try to check them with event.data.object, they are empty. I set these new arguments by adding in the stripe session  metadata: {"user": req.session.username}, client_reference_id : username, yet they are still null

Comment: My best advice is to either contact support to check what's happening, or if you have discord you could join the Stripe Discord server https://stripe.com/go/developer-chat

Comment: yeah, they helped me there! thanks once again